# how to create database and save data of two activities on click of a button in the second activity

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have two activities:

In activity1 - a phone number edittext and a name edittext with a NEXT button to go to activity2.

In activity2 - a radio group with two radio buttons and an edittext with a submit button to save all activity1 and activity2 edittexts and radiobuttons into database.

First of all I would like to know how to create a database in android eclipse java app?

Please help.

Comment: You should make use of `SharedPreferences` to save the data of activity1 as activity2 gets started, and on clicking the button of activity2 you should save both activities data in db

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/ and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html for create and manage database

Answer (score 0):

To create a SQLite Database follow the [official](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) guide.
To pass your data form Activity 1 to 2 you could make use of SharedPreferences or add them to the Intent as a Bundle

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("number", iNumber);
i.putExtra("name", sName);
startActivity(i);
```

In another activity you get this data like bellow.

```
String no = getIntent()..getExtras().getString("number");
String nm = getIntent()..getExtras().getString("name");
```

Comment: In place of "number" i have to type the edittext id from xml?

Comment: No that is string which is used in another activity to get this data

Comment: In another activity you get this data like bellow.

String no = getIntent()..getExtras().getString("number");
String nm = getIntent()..getExtras().getString("name");

Comment: how to write if condition in second activity for data saved from first activity?

Comment: @AJ_app i dont understand your question. Could you exactly explain what do you want to do?